# objectdatasource and caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a dataset that contains around 500 records with 7 columns in each record. I would like to use objectdatasource and caching. I am sure that the data doesn't change. But there will be lots of users accessing the data. My question is whether it would be a good idea to cache the data that has 500 records. is it optimal or not? I think the objectdatasource caches the data per user. so I am wondering whether the data with this size would have performance issues if I cache the data.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Comment: How much memory does the 500 records use?

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the size of the records, not just the number of them.  In any event, ASP.NET's caching algorithm uses a Least Recently Used (LRU) algorithm to evict out items that have not been used recently to make room for additional items.  Thus, unless your site is either extremely busy or your result set extremely large, you should be fine to cache the result set and let ASP.NET's cache handle the details of keeping the most used data in the cache and expiring the least used data.

You might also consider using Page level Output Caching if nothing else on the page is user-specific, as this would likely give you slightly more performance for minimal additional memory usage.  Other areas to investigate are the  control, SqlDependencies, and of course if the data is read-only, be sure you are disabling ViewState on whatever control you're using to display the data.